# ggplot2 geom_point position= "dodges" doesn't match the error bar dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

Im trying to figure out the best way to plot changes in water potential through summer comparing two factors, soil cover treatments and irrigation. I reached a fair result but im having troubles that the geom_points doesn't follow the `position_dodge` as the error bar.

Example:[Best Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPLsH.png)

```
Stats <- summarySE(Maiten, measurevar= "Potencial", groupvars=c("Fecha","Riego","Tratamiento"),na.rm=TRUE)
ggplot(Stats, aes(x=Fecha, y=Potencial, group=Riego, colour=Riego,shape=Tratamiento))+
geom_errorbar(aes(x=Fecha, ymax=Potencial+se, ymin=Potencial-se),position="dodge")+
geom_point(position="dodge",size=3)+theme_classic()
```

Though this code give me this warning "Warning message:
Width not defined. Set with `position_dodge(width = ?)` " if i alter the width neither the error bars or points dodge.

Example: [modifiying position_dodge(width =0.9)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mrat.png)

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what could be happening without a sample of data to work with, but to demonstrate, `position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)` in each geom call should put the dodged parts in the same places:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(Time, weight, colour = Diet)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) 
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
```

[image]

(also to demonstrate here that `stat_summary` will do most of your mean/se plotting within a function call, grouping accordingly)

<sup>Created on 2022-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! i actually replace my factors and data from the code you sent and continue to have the same problem, then i replace the "date" format from my x-axxis and the dodge work out.

Comment: Ah that's interesting! It might have been that `position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)` in your first plotting of the graph was separating your points over 0.9 *days* in the date formatted axis. You could try `width = 10` or similar on a date formatted axis and see if that achieves anything too!